# Calling Widgets Using PHP. WordPress

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

I want call a widget in my WordPress installation using a PHP function or shortcode, directly from a template. I need to call this plugin directly from a template, but there is no shortcode or PHP calling :

```
 <?php
 /*
 Plugin Name: WP Recent Tags
 Plugin URI: http://www.mashget.com/2008/09/18/wp-recent-tags-for-wordpress/
 Description: Show the recent tags.
 Author: Andrew Zhang
 Version: 0.1.1
 Author URI: http://www.mashget.com
 */
 if  (!class_exists('RecentTags')):
 class RecentTags
 {
var $plugin_name="WP Recent Tags";
var $plugin_version="0.1.1";
var $plugin_uri="http://www.mashget.com";

var $wptTable;
var $post_tag_update_count_callback;
var $tagcount_update_log=array();
var $rtOptions;

function RecentTags()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $this->wptTable=$wpdb->prefix . 'wpt_recent_tagcount';
    $this->rtOptions=get_option('widget_recent_tags');
    if(!$this->rtOptions)
    {
        $this->rtOptions=$this->get_def_options();
    }
    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy('post_tag');       
    if (!empty($taxonomy->update_count_callback) ) 
    {
        $this->post_tag_update_count_callback=$taxonomy->update_count_callback;
        $taxonomy->update_count_callback=array(&$this,'post_tag_update_count');
        add_action('wp_insert_post', array(&$this,'check_tagcount_update_log'), PHP_INT_MAX, 2);
    }
    if($this->rtOptions['style_css_enabled'])
    {
        add_action('wp_head', array(&$this,'generate_rtstyle'));
    }

    add_action('delete_term', array(&$this,'deletetagstat'));
    add_action('widgets_init', array(&$this, 'register_wrt_widget' ));
    add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this,'add_options_page'));
}

function get_def_options()
{
    return array(
            'title'=>'Recent Tags',
            'postsnum'=>10,
            'tagsnum'=>15,
            'style'=>'cloud',
            "style_css_enabled" => "1",
            "cloud_style_css" =>"ul.recent-tags li { display:inline; border:0; }
                ul.recent-tags li a { font-weight:400; line-height:120%; margin:0 0.5em 0 0; }
                ul.recent-tags li .S3 { font-size:13pt; }
                ul.recent-tags li .S2 { font-size:11pt; }
                ul.recent-tags li .S1 { font-size:8pt; }
                ",
            "list_style_css" =>"ul.recent-tags li { border:0; }
                ul.recent-tags li a { font-weight:400; line-height:120%; margin:0 0.5em 0 0; }
                ",
        );
}

function add_options_page()
{
    if (function_exists('add_options_page'))
    {
        add_options_page( $this->plugin_name, $this->plugin_name, 8, basename(__FILE__), array(&$this,'wp_recent_tags_options_subpanel'));
    }
}

function wp_recent_tags_options_subpanel()
{
    if($_POST["wp_rt_submit"])
    {
        $wp_settings = array (
            "style_css_enabled" => $_POST['style_css_enabled']? "1":false,
            "cloud_style_css" => $_POST['cloud_style_css'],
            "list_style_css" => $_POST['list_style_css'],
        );
        $wp_settings=array_merge($this->rtOptions, $wp_settings);
        update_option("widget_recent_tags",$wp_settings);
        echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p>Options Updated</p></div>';
    }
    else if($_POST["wp_rt_load_default"])
    {
        $def=$this->get_def_options();
        $wp_settings = array (
            "cloud_style_css" => $def["cloud_style_css"],
            "list_style_css" => $def["list_style_css"],
        );
        $wp_settings=array_merge($this->rtOptions, $wp_settings);
        update_option("widget_recent_tags",$wp_settings);
        echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p>Options Reset</p></div>';
    }
    else
    {
        $wp_settings=$this->rtOptions;
    }
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?page=recent-tags.php" method="post">
        <h2><?php echo $this->plugin_name;?> Options</h2>
        <table class="form-table">
          <tr valign="top">
            <td>        
            <input name="style_css_enabled" type="checkbox" id="style_css_enabled" value="1" <?php checked('1', ($wp_settings["style_css_enabled"]==="1")); ?> />
            <label for=style_css_enabled><strong>Output style in the page</strong></label> (Or you may want to put these in your own css) 
            <p>
                <a name="rt-cloud"></a>
                <label>For Cloud</label>
                <br/>
                <textarea name="cloud_style_css" rows="5" cols="80"><?php echo str_replace("\t","",$wp_settings["cloud_style_css"]); ?></textarea>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a name="rt-list"></a>
                <label>For List</label>
                <br/>
                <textarea name="list_style_css" rows="5" cols="80"><?php echo str_replace("\t","",$wp_settings["list_style_css"]); ?></textarea>
            </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <p class="submit">
          <input type="submit" name="wp_rt_load_default" value="Reset to Default Options &raquo;" class="button" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to reset options?')" />
          <input type="submit" name="wp_rt_submit" value="Save Options &raquo;" class="button" style="margin-left:15px;" />
        </p>  
      </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function register_wrt_widget()
{
    if (!function_exists( 'register_sidebar_widget' ))return;
    register_sidebar_widget($this->plugin_name, array(&$this, 'generate_wrt_widget' ));
    register_widget_control($this->plugin_name, array(&$this, 'wrt_widget_control' ) );
}

function wrt_widget_control()
{   
    $options = $newoptions = $this->rtOptions;
    if (isset($_POST['recent-tags-title'])) 
    {
        $newoptions['title'] =(stripslashes($_POST['recent-tags-title']));
        $newoptions['postsnum']=intval($_POST['recent-tags-rcposts-num']);
        $newoptions['tagsnum']=intval($_POST['recent-tags-maxtags-num']);
        $newoptions['style']=($_POST['recent-tags-style']);
    }
    if ( $options != $newoptions ) 
    {
        if($newoptions['postsnum'] > $options['postsnum'])
        {
            $this->preRtdata(intval($newoptions['postsnum']));
        }
        $options = $newoptions;
        update_option('widget_recent_tags', $options);
    }       

    $title = attribute_escape($options['title'] );
    $postsnum = $options['postsnum'];
    $tagsnum =$options['tagsnum'];

    if(!class_exists("WidgetCache"))
    {
        ?>
        <p>
        <i>
        You might use <a href='http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-widget-cache/' target='_blank'>
        WP Widget Cache</a> 
        to improve performance</i>
        </p>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <p>
    <label for="recent-tags-title">
    Title: <input type="text" id="recent-tags-title" name="recent-tags-title" value="<?php echo $title ?>" style="width: 200px;"/>
    </label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="recent-tags-maxtags-num">
    Number of tags to show: <input type="text" size="2" id="recent-tags-maxtags-num" name="recent-tags-maxtags-num" value="<?php echo $tagsnum ?>"  style="text-align:center;"/>
    </label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="recent-tags-rcposts-num">
    Show the tags in recent <input type="text" size="2" id="recent-tags-rcposts-num" name="recent-tags-rcposts-num" value="<?php echo $postsnum ?>" style="text-align:center;"/> posts
    </label> (<a href="http://www.mashget.com/2008/09/18/wp-recent-tags-for-wordpress/#recent" target="_blank">?</a>)
    </p>    
    <p>
    Output style: 
        <label for="recent-tags-style-cloud">
            <input type="radio" id="recent-tags-style-cloud" name="recent-tags-style" value="cloud" <?php checked('1', $options['style']=="cloud"); ?> /> Cloud
        </label> (<a href='/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=recent-tags.php#rt-cloud' target='_blank'>css</a>)
        <label for="recent-tags-style-list">
            <input type="radio" id="recent-tags-style-list" name="recent-tags-style" value="list" <?php checked('1', $options['style']=="list"); ?> /> List
        </label> (<a href='/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=recent-tags.php#rt-list' target='_blank'>css</a>)
    </p>
    <?php
}

function generate_rtstyle()
{
    echo "<!--$this->plugin_name $this->plugin_version ($this->plugin_uri) Begin -->\n";
    echo "<style>\n";
    echo str_replace("\t","",$this->rtOptions[$this->rtOptions['style']."_style_css"]);
    echo "</style>\n";
    echo "<!--$this->plugin_name End -->\n";
}

function generate_wrt_widget($args)
{
    extract($args);
    {
        $options = $this->rtOptions;

        $title = $options['title'];
        $postsnum =intval($options['postsnum']);    
        $tagsnum = intval($options['tagsnum']);

        if(!($postsnum>0&&$tagsnum>0))return;

        echo "<!--$this->plugin_name $this->plugin_version ($this->plugin_uri) Begin -->\n";
        echo $before_widget;
        echo $before_title.$title. $after_title;

        $sdate=$this->getRecentPostDate($postsnum);

        echo "<ul class='recent-tags'>";
        if($options['style']=='cloud')
        {   
            $rts=$this->getRecentTagCloud($tagsnum, $sdate, 3); 
            foreach ($rts as $lpterm)
            {
            ?>
                <li><a class="S<?php echo $lpterm['slevel']; ?>" href="<?php echo $lpterm['link']; ?>" title="View all posts tagged with <?php echo $lpterm['name'];?>"><?php echo $lpterm['name'];?></a></li>
            <?php
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
        else 
        {
            $rts=$this->getRecentTagNameLinks($tagsnum, $sdate);    
            echo "<ul class='recent-tags'>";
            foreach ($rts as $lpterm)
            {
            ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $lpterm['link']; ?>" title="View all posts tagged with <?php echo $lpterm['name'];?>"><?php echo $lpterm['name'];?></a></li>
            <?php
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo $after_widget;
        echo "<!--$this->plugin_name End -->\n";
    }
}

function post_tag_update_count($terms)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $msg="";
    foreach ( $terms as $term )
    {
        if(!$this->tagcount_update_log[$term])
        {
            $this->tagcount_update_log[$term]=array();

            $rec=$wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT count, term_id FROM $wpdb->term_taxonomy WHERE term_taxonomy_id = %d", $term ));
            if(!$rec) continue;

            $oldcount=$rec->count;
            $term_id=$rec->term_id;
        }
        else
        {
            $oldcount=$this->tagcount_update_log[$term]['oldcount'];
            $term_id=$this->tagcount_update_log[$term]['term_id'];
        }

        $newcount = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->term_relationships, $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' AND term_taxonomy_id = %d", $term ) );
        //$wpdb->update($wpdb->term_taxonomy, compact( 'count' ), array( 'term_taxonomy_id' => $term ));

        $this->tagcount_update_log[$term]=array(
        'oldcount'=>intval($oldcount),
        'newcount'=>intval($newcount),
        'term_id'=>intval($term_id)
        );
    }
    //call_user_func($this->post_tag_update_count_callback, $terms);
}

function check_tagcount_update_log($post_id=0, $post=null)
{
    if(!($post_id > 0))return;
    if(!$post || 'publish' != $post->post_status)return;

    global $wpdb;
    foreach ($this->tagcount_update_log as $term_taxonomy_id=>$termArr)
    {
        if($termArr['oldcount']!=$termArr['newcount'])
        {
            $v=$wpdb->update($wpdb->term_taxonomy, array('count'=>$termArr['newcount']), array( 'term_taxonomy_id' => $term_taxonomy_id ));
            //file_put_contents(dirname(__File__)."/".$term_taxonomy_id,var_export($termArr,true));
            $this->updatetagstat($termArr['term_id'], $termArr['newcount']-$termArr['oldcount']);
        }
    }
    $this->tagcount_update_log=array();
}

function updatetagstat($term_id=0, $countchange=0, $timestamp=null)
{
    $term_id=intval($term_id);
    $countchange=intval($countchange);

    global $wpdb;
    if(!($term_id>0) || $countchange==0 ) return;

    if(!$timestamp)$timestamp=time();
    if(!is_int($timestamp))$timestamp=strtotime($timestamp);

    $today = date("Ymd", $timestamp);
    $tomorrow =date("Ymd", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m",$timestamp)  , date("d",$timestamp)+1, date("Y",$timestamp)));

    $sql="select wpt_id, count from $this->wptTable where term_id='$term_id' and inc_date>='$today' and inc_date<'$tomorrow'";
    $rec=$wpdb->get_row($sql);

    $sql="";
    if($rec)
    {
        $recid=$rec->wpt_id;        
        if($countchange < 0)
        {
            if($countchange < -$rec->count)
            {
                $countchange = -$rec->count;
            }
        }
        $sql="update $this->wptTable set count=count + ($countchange) where wpt_id ='$recid'";
    }
    else if($countchange > 0)
    {
        $sql="insert into $this->wptTable (term_id,count,inc_date) values ('$term_id','$countchange','$today')";
    }
    if($sql)$wpdb->query($sql);
}

function deletetagstat($term=0, $tt_id=0, $taxonomy=0)
{
    global $wpdb;
    if(!($term > 0))return;
    $sql="delete from $this->wptTable where term_id='$term'";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
}

function install()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $wptTable=$this->wptTable;

    if($wpdb->get_var("show tables like '$wptTable'") != $wptTable) {

        $sql="CREATE TABLE {$wptTable}
            (
                wpt_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                term_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                count BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED default '0',
                inc_date DATETIME NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
                PRIMARY KEY  (wpt_id),
                INDEX inc_date (inc_date),
                INDEX term_id (term_id)
            )";

        $wpdb->query($sql);         
        $this->preRtdata(10);
        //file_put_contents(dirname(__File__)."/active",$wpdb->query($sql));
    }
}

function preRtdata($num)
{   
    if($num<=0)return;
    set_time_limit(0);
    global $wpdb;
    $termArr=$this->getTagsInRecentPosts($num);
    $lastTerm=$termArr[sizeof($termArr)-1];
    $sql="Delete from $this->wptTable where inc_date < '{$lastTerm['date']}'";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
    foreach ($termArr as $term)
    {
        $this->updatetagstat($term['term_id'], 1, $term['date']);
    }
}

function getRecentTags($limit, $days)
{       
    global $wpdb;
    $where="";
    if( is_int($days) && $days > 0)
    {
        $mday =date("Ymd", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")-$days, date("Y")));
        $where=" WHERE inc_date >= '$mday' ";
    }
    else if( is_object($days) && $days->post_date)
    {
        $days=strtotime($days->post_date);
        $mday=date("Ymd", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m",$days)  , date("d",$days), date("Y",$days)));
        $where=" WHERE inc_date >= '$mday' ";
    }
    $sql= "SELECT sum(count) as sum , t.term_id, name FROM $this->wptTable As s INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms As t on s.term_id=t.term_id $where GROUP BY term_id ORDER BY sum DESC LIMIT 0, $limit";
    $terms = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    return $terms;
}

function getRecentTagNameLinks($limit, $days)
{
    $res=array();
    $terms=$this->getRecentTags($limit, $days);
    foreach ($terms as $term)
    {
        $res[] = array(
        "id"=>$term->term_id,
        "name"=>$term->name,
        "link"=>clean_url(get_tag_link($term->term_id)),
        "sum"=>$term->sum
        );
    }
    return $res;
}

function cmplp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}

function getRecentTagCloud($limit, $days, $levelcount)
{
    $lpterms=$this->getRecentTagNameLinks($limit, $days);

    $lpsize=sizeof($lpterms);
    $lpStep=floor($lpsize/$levelcount);
    $lpfp=0;
    $lplevel=$levelcount;

    $minsum=intval($lpterms[$lpsize-1]['sum'])-1;
    $maxsum=intval($lpterms[0]['sum']);

    foreach ($lpterms as $key => $lpterm)
    {
        $lpterms[$key]['slevel']=ceil(((floatval($lpterm['sum']))-$minsum)/($maxsum-$minsum)*$levelcount);
        $lpterms[$key]['level']=$lplevel;
        $lpfp++;
        if($lpfp == $lpStep)
        {
            $lplevel--;
            $lpfp=0;
        }
    }

    usort($lpterms, array(&$this, 'cmplp' ));
    return $lpterms;
}

function cleartagstat($days)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $mday =date("Ymd", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")-$days, date("Y")));
    $sql = "delete FROM $this->wptTable WHERE inc_date < '$mday' ";
    return $wpdb->query($sql);
}

function getRecentPostDate($num)
{
    global $wpdb, $tableposts;  
    $q = "SELECT post_date FROM $tableposts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY post_date DESC limit $num, 1";
    $res= $wpdb->get_results($q);
    return $res[0];
}

function getTagsInRecentPosts($num)
{
    global $wpdb, $tableposts;  
    $q = "SELECT ID, post_date FROM $tableposts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ORDER BY post_date DESC limit $num";
    $res= $wpdb->get_results($q);
    $termIdArr=array();
    foreach ($res as $post)
    {       
        $tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);
        if ($tags && is_array($tags)) 
        {
            foreach ($tags as $tag) 
            {
                $termIdArr[]= array(
                    "term_id"=>$tag->term_id,
                    "date"=>$post->post_date
                );              
            }
        }
    }       
    return $termIdArr;
}
 }
 endif;

 $recentTags= & new RecentTags();
 register_activation_hook(__File__, array($recentTags,"install"));
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call to this function: generate_wrt_widget($args).

$args should be loaded with the options you need, you can see on the function's code the variables that can be loaded in it.